# как узнать байты определенного символа

Tags: java, кодировка

Допустим у меня есть символ из Юникода например 'Ы', как узнать какими байтами он представлен в кодировке UTF-8?

Comment: Вам нужен цифровой код символа? или я что-то не так понял

Comment: например букве присвоен номер какой-то юникода скажем 1234, и мне нужен массив байтов в который разложен этот номер в кодировке  utf-8, т.е. нужен ответ в виде 43,12,17

Comment: Все-таки поясните, зачем это вам? Хотите узнать коды нескольких символов, набрерите их в текстовом файле и посмотрите в hex-просмотрщике.

Comment: это просто задача, в оригенале так звучит: Какими байтами представляется символ 'Ы' в кодировке UTF-8? Введите десятичные значения байт через пробел, например, 10 34 254. Важно что 'Ы' char а не string

Comment: Мне кажется, что задача хоть и учебная, но полезная для сообщества. Не нужно закрывать вопрос.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
String example = "Convert Java String";
byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

Comment: да, сначало я тоже так сделал, например если  example = "Ы"
то вывод: [-37]
в юникоде Ы присвоено число 1067, которое не может быть разложено в 1 байт, где то наверно явно кодировку надо указать но 
'byte[] bytes = example.getBytes("UTF-8");' компилятор не пропускат, хотя должен

Comment: Только не забывайте, что в Java строки хранятся в UTF-16

Comment: @ketchyn, у меня выводит [-48, -85].

Comment: @ketchyn, и да, `getBytes("UTF-8");` не пропускается, потому что `throws UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: Все разобрался, есть метод `Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();`. У меня стоит кодировка  "windows 1251",  и если вызвать пустой  `getBytes()` то будет эта кодировка, если явно указать `getBytes("UTF-8")` , у которого есть проверяемое исключение, как правильно замечено, то возвращает  [-48, -85].

Comment: Нет неправильно, сервер где задана эта задача не пропустил ответ, видимо строка "Ы" и символ 'Ы' поразному кодируется, и байты потом разный вытаскиваются, как из char вытащить байты по UTF-8?

Comment: @ketchyn, imho **правильным решением** будет программа, которая в соответствии с [описанием utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) честно преобразует Char в последовательность байт.

Comment: @ketchyn, я с вами не согласен. Даже если вы не будете использовать String в реализации сего, результат будет аналогичным.

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = "Ы";
byte [] b = s.getBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(((int)b[i] ^ -1<<8)+" ");
}
```

Так все байты приводятся к инту и получается правильная десятичная кодировка

Answer (score 0):

```
String original = new String("Ы");
byte[] defaultBytes = original.getBytes();
for (byte b : defaultBytes) {
    System.out.println(b & 0xFF);
}
```

Альтернативный вариан решения задачи. В этом случае мы получаем необходимые 8 левых бит путем логического уможения байта массива на 0xFF, которое соответвует 11111111 и остальным нулям правее.